# If subtitle present issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the newest wordpress.

In my theme, I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
   if (the_subtitle() == "") {
       echo the_title();
   } else {
       echo the_subtitle();
   } ?>
```

Each page has a default title. Some pages have a subtitle. If there IS a subtitle, then the title shouldn't be displayed and the subtitle should take it's place.

But right now for some reason, it's displaying the subtitle and THEN the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call echo. It already echoes.

```
<?php
   if (the_subtitle("","", false) == "") {
       the_title();
   } else {
       the_subtitle();
   } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now with this code: `<?php if (get_the_subtitle() == "") { the_subtitle(); } else { the_title(); } ?>`, I for some reason get the subtitle repeating twice?